# Should added fields be visible in lower API versions?

Tags: rest, eloquent, laravel-5.3, api-design

In building a REST API, should fields that are added to a response in version 2 return with the response from a call to the version 1 end point?

As an example, given the endpoint `api/v1/users/1`, the response could be:

```
{
    "first_name":"david"
}
```

Then in v2, given the endpoint `api/v2/users/1`, the response could be updated to be:

```
{
    "first_name":"david",
    "last_name":"smith"
}
```

Would it be bad practice to have the same response returned from a call to the v2 endpoint returned on a call to the v1 endpoint? My initial thought is yes, but then again I am not seeing an issue since this change wouldn't be breaking.

As a side note, the question arose from trying to figure out how build a versioned api using Laravel and Eloquent. I can't easily see a way to accomplish this with Eloquent, and would need to map the model to a versioned one, or write all of my repositories with the QueryBuilder to controll the fields. Tagged as Laravel and Eloquent since those are the specific frameworks that I am using and want to see if anyone has a solution using those, but the question is for api design in general.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just adding properties, you (probably) don't need to version your API. Well-behaved clients will ignore any new properties. In most cases, adding properties is considered a non-breaking change.

Changing your V1 API response to include the new properties and adding a V2 that looks exactly the same as V1 is silly. Don't do that. There's no value in two versions that look the same.

If you are making breaking changes, then updating the V1 API to have those changes also is a terrible idea and you shouldn't do that.

I can't speak to Laravel and Eloquent.